# cakephp 3.2.3 query on date not working

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

So here is the query, it just comes back empty, It should have multiple results. any idea what this query should look like?

```
    $bookings = $orders->find()->where(["DATE('Orders.booking_date_time')" => $date_time]);
```

Here is the date in the DB 2016-07-17 15:00:00
Here is what is being passed in 2016-07-17 15:00:00

Comment: Do you know what the MySQL `DATE()` function actually does? **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date**

Comment: If I take off the where clause I get
'code'
{
    "bookings": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "tour_id": 6,
            "customer_id": 1,
            "booking_date_time": "2016-07-17T15:00:00+0000",
            "created": "2015-12-17T11:35:47+0000",
            "modified": "2015-12-17T11:35:47+0000",
            "active": 0
        }
    ]
}

Comment: That is to be expected... but that has nothing to do with my "question", which is more of a broad hint actually.

Comment: it worked with this         $bookings = $orders->find('all')->where(['Orders.booking_date_time' => $date_time, 'Orders.tour_id' => $tour_id]);

Answer (score 0):

```
    $bookings = $orders->find('all')->where(['Orders.booking_date_time' => $date_time, 'Orders.tour_id' => $tour_id]);
```

This was the correct query I was looking for.